# How to create temporary table using a common table expression

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to use Temporary table after ;with clause PostgreSQL inside function. I am getting error  **syntax error at or near "create"**.

this is code

```
with counts as(
    select
        
        (   
            select count(cte."Id") from cte 
            left join "Medication" m3 on m3."Id" = cte."Id"  and m3."AlfId" = any(_alfids::int[])
            where public."CheckMedicationStatus"(m3, '{Active}') = true and cte."ResidentId" = ri."ResidentId" 
        ) as "ActiveCount",
        (   
            select count(cte."Id") from cte 
            left join "Medication" m3 on m3."Id" = cte."Id"  and m3."AlfId" = any(_alfids::int[])
            where public."CheckMedicationStatus"(m3, '{Pending}') = true and cte."ResidentId" = ri."ResidentId" 
        ) as "PendingCount"
        
    from residentIds ri --where false = true
)
Create  TEMPORARY  table ("ActiveCount" int, "PendingCount" int)as 
    select * from counts
;
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CREATE TABLE needs to be before the common table expression

```
create temp table foo
as
with cte1 as (
  ...
), cte2 as (
 ...
), cte3 as (
 ...
), cte4 as (
 ...
), cte5 as (
 ...
) 
select *
from cte5;
```

Comment: Ok this works but when I try to insert into temp table it still give error at same point

**create temp table foo
with counts as (
  ...
)
insert into temp as
   select * from counts;**

Comment: No, you don't need `insert` (and you can't use it) when you use `create table .. as select`

Comment: actually I have 5 with clauses and at the last with I want to insert data into temp table to be used latter but this is not working

Comment: The number of CTEs doesn't matter. You simply can't use `insert` when you use `create table .. as select`. All you need is the final `select` - the insert is implied

Comment: I want to store the cte4 result in temp table and then use it for querying cte1  and joining it

Comment: This answers your direct question on why the create temp table did not work. What you describe now is a completely different question (and it doesn't make sense to begin with - why the need for a temp table if you already have the result in a CTE?)

Comment: actually temp table is fast as it bypass the WAL. so I want to use it to make query fast

Comment: A CTE bypasses WAL as sell

Comment: yes but that is taking time and temp table will work fast I think so that is why I am using it